# Single line for all static Functions in Selenium Webdriver.By

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
var findById = driver.findElement(By.id("id"))
var findByClass = driver.findElement(By.className("class"))
var findByXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))
```

is it possible to replace all of the right side in the above by a single line; say

```
var dynamicLocator = "id" | "className" | "xpath";
var find = driver.findElement(By.dynamicLocator("something"))
```

I understand it's a matter of fiddling with quotes, But ans seems to elude me.

Comment: "something" in above code is the actual value of "id" or "className" or "xpath" attribute? Additionally, through **dynamicLocator** method above do you want to match the input value with the value of each attribute present in variable dynamicLocator?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cssSelector` instead of `xpath` you can use or `,`. For example for html

```
<div class="parentClass">
  <div id="targetId" class="targetClass"></div>
</div>
```

You can do

```
By dynamicLocator = By.cssSelector("#targetId, .targetClass, .parentClass > .targetId");
```

This will return the first element it founds by ID `targetId` or by class `targetClass` or element with class `targetClass` witch is direct child of element with class `parentClass` (with `xpath` it will look like  `//div[@class='parentClass']/div[@class='targetClass']`).